# Converting Normal Form to CNF

Tags: logic

In my CS Logic class we have to convert normal form boolean expressions to CNF, but I am kind of stuck on this one.

¬(¬P => (P => Q))

which is:

¬(¬P => (¬P OR Q)) by implication elimination

¬(¬¬P OR (¬P OR Q)) by implication elimination

¬(P OR (¬P OR Q)) by double negation

¬P AND ¬(¬P OR Q)) by DeMorgan's

¬P AND (¬¬P AND ¬Q)) by DeMorgan's

¬P AND (P AND ¬Q)) by double negation

The next step is to distribute OR over AND, but there aren't any OR to distribute.

Answer (score 0):

Once you reach

- `¬(P OR (¬P OR Q))` by double negation

you have

- `¬((P OR ¬P) OR (P OR Q))` by distribution
- `¬(true OR (P OR Q))` by excluded middle
- `¬(true)` by null element of `OR`
- `false` by obviousness :P